# Remote IP Address for HttpServletRequest Object being obscured by Apache Proxy

Tags: java, apache, proxy, ip

I am writing an application in Java that serves a web page with data from an underlying database.  I am limiting access to the web page based on some IP restrictions.  Basically any IP that falls into the 'Accepted' range will be allowed to access the web page and any IP outside of this range will be redirected to an error page.  To get the IP address of the user attempting to access the page I am using the following:

```
String userIPAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Where 'request' is my HttpServletRequest Object.

The issue I am running into is that this web page is being proxied through an Apache Web Server.

When this happens, it loses the clients IP address and adopts the IP address of our firewall.  So when I access request.getRemoteAddr(), it will return the same IP no matter where the customer attempts to access the web page from.

When accessing the web page internally via direct IP address my IP check works just fine.  The issue presents itself when you access through the proxy.

Is there anything that I can do programmatically to access the clients actual IP address?  Or is this something that has to be done/changed via the Apache web server to allow this information to pass through?  In that case I can post to Server Fault if that would be a better forum.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4):

When acting in a reverse-proxy mode (using the ProxyPass directive, for example), Apache [mod_proxy_http](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) adds several request headers in order to pass information to the origin server, one of them being the `X-Forwarded-For` which will contain the IP address of the client.

Keep in mind that, if the original request already contained this header (which is not unusual at all), Apache will append the client IP address to existig value(s) so you will get comma+space separated list of IP addresses.  The last (rightmost) IP address is always the IP address that connects to the last proxy (your Apache), which means that is the one you want to test against.

Comment: This is very helpful information.  When using ProxyPass with HTTP, is the X-Forwarded-For header included automatically?  Or do I need to configure something within Apache to include this?

Comment: It should be there by default, just look at `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` (or something like that, I am not the Java expert :))

Comment: X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2    <br/>                                              
where the value is a comma+space separated list of IP addresses, the left-most being the original client, and each successive proxy that passed the request adding the IP address where it received the request from. In this example, the request passed through proxy1, proxy2, and then proxy3 (not shown in the header). proxy3 appears as remote address of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this programmatically.  I don't think it is even possible to change something in the Apache web server.

Is sounds like your firewall is masquerading incoming IP addresses. I think the solution is in the configuration of your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use the AJP protocol instead of HTTP in the Apache proxy.

Apparently this retains the client's IP address.  Does anyone have any ideas why?

Use:

```
ProxyPass /APPLICATION_NAME ajp://IP_ADDRESS:8009/APPLICATION_NAME
```

Instead of:

```
<Location "/APPLICATION_NAME">
    ProxyPass  http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/APPLICATION_NAME
    ProxyPassReverse http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/APPLICATION_NAME
</Location>
```

In the .conf proxy file.

This enabled me to grab the IP from the client without it being overwritten during the proxy.  I did not have to change any code either.  After changing to AJP in the Apache proxy file, the following contained the correct IP address:

```
String userIPAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```